# Converting Object into "something else" before Serializing it using FasterXML Jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, fasterxml

`public void serialize(IPerson person, OutputStream output) throws Exception {}`

`public void deserialize(InputStream input) throws Exception {}`

I have an interface named IPerson, it has basic functionality.

I want to serialize the person object and be able to deserialize it from the deserialize method.

However, the scenario is this I cannot use Java's serializable interface as I can't be sure what implementation of IPerson will be used.

I have chosen to use **`Jackson's FasterXML`**, using `ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();`

The problem I am having is that since IPerson is an interface I cannot serialize it directly using `mapper.writerValue(output, person)`, I figured I must convert this object into something else, say a ByteArray then serialize it?

Also, this would be converting this something else into an object when deserializing? I have minimal experience with what exactly I should convert this object to and how to do so? Any ideas?

Comment: If you were to convert an object to a byte array, that would require serializing it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the default `ObjectMapper` you will have to make sure the objects you serialize are *Java Beans*. For non-bean classes you can set field visibility using `m.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);` or annotate your class using `@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)`.

For deserializing you will have to tell the `ObjectMapper` the target type. This can be done by providing a concrete implementation type to `readValue` or by storing the classname within the exported JSON. For this you can set `m.enableDefaultTypingAsProperty(DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE, "__class");` and annotate your objects with `@JsonTypeInfo`

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.enableDefaultTypingAsProperty(DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE, "__class");

IPerson value = new MyPerson();
String s = om.writeValueAsString(value);
IPerson d = om.readValue(s, IPerson.class);
```

using

```
interface IPerson {
   void doSomething();
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property = "__class")
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
class MyPerson implements IPerson {
    String name;

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
    }
}
```

Note that, you will need a default constructor for this to work or work with `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonProperty` (see [jackson-annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations) for details)